# How to hide my api and copy json into own array

Tags: javascript, json, api

I started programming and I build my own website for fun.

So I have the following questions:

I want to fetch a Api, but I don't know how to secure my apikey and the api which is used.

Q: How I can hide my code? I want to call the Api every 15min with a Cronjobs and push the wanted data to a array, then generate a Table with the data.

Q: How I can take json data and create my own json out of that? I just want to update my data every 15min and don't wanna call the api everytime my script is loaded in the browser

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how you are serving your website, or what it is written in. If you are using Express:

1. You need to keep the API key on your server and not pass it to the client.

2.

```
const JSONCache = {}

setInterval(() => 
   axios.get(thirdPartyAPI)
   .then(({data}) => (JSONCache = data)), 15 * 60 * 1000)

get('/jsondata', (req, res) => res.sendJSON(JSONCache))
```

If you are using a static server like Apache, then you need to write the JSON to a file in your cron task:

```
#!/bin/node

const axios = require('axios')
const fs = require('fs')

axios.get(thirdPartyAPI)
   .then(({data}) => fs.writeFileSync(pathToFile, JSON.stringify(data), 'utf8')), 15 * 60 * 1000)
```

I would save it as stringified JSON somewhere that the web server can serve it from, then in your client code, fetch it and render it in the page as a table using templating.